# Is it good practice, in the same post, to add the paraphrase of other answers to an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was observing the post [Is it okay to keep a "Thank you" slide before references?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/150197/is-it-okay-to-keep-a-thank-you-slide-before-references/150215#150215).

The top-voted **answer**, https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/150198/73304, has recently *added* a paraphrase of what other posters suggest further down in the list of **answers**.
It is clearly stated that the text is added and is not one's own original: see https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/150198/timeline#history_43752c6d-0656-415c-b707-6a90e6b04032

I wondered whether one ought to refrain from summarizing **in one's own answer** the array of **answers** given to the same question, in the meantime by other people.

I would like to read your considerations in the positive and in the negative. Feel free to downvote, of course, if this question does not show any research effort, is unclear or is not useful; a short explanation to realise this will be appreciated at any rate.

Comment: Which comments? If they were under the answer itself, it's definitely good practice, that's what comments *are* for.

Comment: @Glorfindel I have rephrased one line in post to clarify the point you raised, while the title of the post and final question still apply. The crux not about incorporating the comments to one's own answer, but the content of others' answers. The links provide a possibility to look for oneself, independent of my wording being inaccurate. You may wish to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the concrete example you link to, it was pointed [in a comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/150197/is-it-okay-to-keep-a-thank-you-slide-before-references/150198#comment400207_150198) that the original revision of the answer was incomplete, as it didn't directly address the core of the question as asked by the OP ("This question was about thank you slides not references [...]"). The answer author, presumably agreeing with the comment, included an addendum which happens to concur with the other answers. In this specific case, that looks completely fine.

> I wondered whether one ought to refrain from summarizing in one's own answer the array of answers given to the same question, in the meantime by other people.

I believe the two main issues when it comes to incorporating content by other answers are:

- Is there adequate attribution; and
- Besides the borrowed parts, is there enough additional content to justify the existence of the answer?

In particular, the second point should, in a large majority of cases, rule out later answers that *only* exist to summarise other answers, as well as edits that completely overwrite an answer with a solution taken from a different answer. In any case, answers should be evaluated on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks. One remark: in the concrete example, there are only three comments (few, not even several, while the author mentions _many_ comments instead), and the content of the addition is borrowed from other answers and comments down the discussion page, which are many. And thanks for clarifying your view on the main issues to consider.

Comment: @XavierStuvw On your remark, I think it's just a matter of phrasing. As I see it, the "many commenters" in the addendum refers generally to people who shared their views in the Q&A, and not just those who posted comments in the literal SE sense.

Comment: I feel the same about the usage of _commenters_, although here this caused confusion and possibly downvotes when I reused that word in my post just above (see Glorfindel's comment, which prompted me to edit). It remains that the content of the addition borrows from other answers (by commenters/posters), namely _Consider verbal thanks and just your conclusions on the final slide, perhaps with a request for questions_. And that's indeed the practice about which I wanted to understand whether is good or bad.